A question about the function $f(x)=x+x^{-1}$ over a field
Let $\mathbb F$ be a field and
consider the function
$$
f(x)=x+x^{-1}
$$
Is there always an extension field $\mathbb E$ of $\mathbb F$ such that $f$ is surjective over $\mathbb E$? That is, such that for every $a\in\mathbb F$, there exists $x\in\mathbb E$ such that $f(x)=a$.
My attempt: If the characteristic of $\mathbb F$ is not $2$, then we adjoint $\mathbb F$ all square roots $\sqrt{a^2-4}$, where $a\in\mathbb F$ (so the equation $f(x)=a$ is solvable).

Please fix all the misspellings. It makes it hard to tell if "subjective" should me "surjective", or some other more obscure concept.

Thanks...it is the blame of auto correcting.

"Feild". "Charterstic". If English isn't your native language then I can understand why those might not jump out to you as misspellings, but can you enable spellcheck? If you post here lots of people are going to read what you wrote - I think writing clearly shows consideration towards them.

Thanks @Eric Towers. But $\mathbb C$  is an extention of $\mathbb Q$ and over $\mathbb C$, $f$ is onto $\mathbb Q$?

Neither extenTion nor exPAnsion.

Please do not answer in the comments, @schiepy

Why the answer of @schipy was deleted? It was actually helpfull.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure

"$f$ is surjective over $\mathbb E$" makes no sense. $f$ is defined from $\Bbb F^$ to $\Bbb F$, or to $\Bbb E^$ to $\Bbb E$. Not from $\Bbb E$ or $\Bbb E^*$ to $\Bbb F$. Better remove that piece of the question, and only leave what follows "That is".

@boaz Because answering in the comments is against the site guidelines. Comments for clarifications, Answers for answers, quite simple, but many users ignore this. For more information please read this thread and the guidelines for comments.

If for all $a\ne0$ you have $x+\dfrac1x=a$ then always the equation$x^2-ax+1=0$ would be reducible which is not possible.

I didn't think it was enough for an answer but whatever.

@Piquito: why is it not possible for every equation of the form $x^2 - ax + 1 = 0$ to have a root? That holds in any algebraically closed field.

@RobArthan: Because solving the equation as usual  the radicand of the square root cannot be a square for all $a$ in the field of base considered. Obviously yes in some extension but with "new" elements as roots.

But the question is asking you whether you can extend $\Bbb{F}$ so that this equation has a root.
